# Java rx nested asychronous calls

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java

I am working with the java rx library now, I am having problems with the internal calls with flatMap and map, for some reason the most internal call is not been done.

Besides, if I replace the flatMap with suscribe() in the internal call, (before the childrenItemsResponse.forEach code), this code is executed, bat the execution is not synchronous, I mean this call is done after the main flatMap execution finish.

This is my code:

```
override fun getSportList(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Single<List<EntityBrowse>> {
        return dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext).flatMap { item ->
            val entityBrowseList = arrayListOf<EntityBrowse>()
            val section = builSection(item?.firstOrNull()!!)
            if (item.firstOrNull()?.collections?.get("NavItems")?.size!! > 0) {
                dCSServiceContext.contentIds = item.firstOrNull()?.collections?.get("NavItems")
                buildNavItems(dCSServiceContext).map { section ->
                    return@map section
                }.map { items ->
                    section.items = items
                    return@map entityBrowseList
                }
            } else {
                Single.just(entityBrowseList)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is presented in the buildNavItems, method:

```
private fun buildNavItems(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Single<MutableList<Item>> {
        return dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext).map { itemsResponse ->
            val items: MutableList<Item> = arrayListOf()
            itemsResponse.forEach { item ->
                val transformedItem = buildItem(item!!)
                if (item?.collections?.get("NavItems") != null) {
                    dCSServiceContext.contentIds = item?.collections?.get("NavItems")
                    val childrenItems: MutableList<Item> = arrayListOf()
                    dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext).flatMap { childrenItemsResponse ->
                        childrenItemsResponse.forEach { childrenItem ->
                            val transformedChildrenItem = buildItem(childrenItem!!)
                            childrenItems.add(transformedChildrenItem)
                        }
                        val section = Section("", "", false,childrenItems )
                        val data = Data(section)
                        val children = Children(data)
                        transformedItem.children = children
                        items.add(transformedItem)
                        Single.just(items)
                    }
                } else {
                    val transformedItem = buildItem(item!!)
                    items.add(transformedItem)
                }
            }
            return@map items
            //Single.just(items)
        }
    }
```

More specifically, the in the line code: `dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext).flatMap { childrenItemsResponse ->`

This code is never executed.

I am not sure about what could be the cause of the issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To activate an observer chain, there has to be a subscription. You don't subscribe to the observer chain that starts with `dCSService...`. `flatMap()` itself won't subscribe to its interior observables until the outer observable chain has been subscribed to.

Comment: Sorry I did something like:                                                                                   
        Observable.just(dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext))
                .map { it }
                .subscribe { println(it)} ... the rest of the code.                                                                     But in both cases, inside .map and inside subscribe I am not able to access to the real values and work with them, also do you know, how can I return this answer to the transformedItem? Thanks!!