# How extract, work and return info from Observable java rx 1.2 and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java

I am working with an observer chain. I am subscribing the call method of an intern call, just like:

```
 Observable.just(dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext))
                .map { "hello " + it }
                .subscribe { println(it)}
```

In both cases, inside the map and the subscribe, I am getting an Observable, any ideas of how can I access to the objects from the observable? Those objects are of type:

```
Single<List<DCSItem?>>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the return type of `dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext)`?

Comment: You are wrapping the `Single` inside the `Observable.just`, you just need to map `dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext)` directly

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that, if I get rid of the observable and I use map directly, this code is not been called , this problem is related with:  
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890373/java-rx-nested-asychronous-calls). The return type is: Single<List<DCSItem?>>

Answer (score 0):

as i im understanding if inside the map you get a single you are using wrong operator. you dont need to use Observable.just to start a stream because you have a stream already so you can do it like this

```
 dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext)
            .map { "hello " + it }
            .subscribe { println(it)}
```

if you want the list to be emitted one by one you can use

```
 dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext)
            .flatMapIterable(item -> item)
            .map { "hello " + it }
            .subscribe { println(it)}
```

Comment: I am working with java rx 1.2 version, this code didn't work for me. My real problem is trying to do the recursives calls in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890373/java-rx-nested-asychronous-calls. I don´t have idea of how I can access to execute this chain of the code.

Comment: I am getting the issue: unresolved reference flatMapiterable

Comment: What dCSService.get(dCSServiceContext) return

Comment: It returns a Single of List of an entity :  Single<List<DCSItem?>>

Comment: Try to add .toObservable befor flatmapiterable

Comment: I am getting the next issue: Type mismatch. Required: (DCSltem?) -. Unit Found: (DCSltem?) -. Any! 
Type inference failed: fun <R : Any!> flatMapIterable ( collectionSelector: Fund <in MutableList<Item>!, out (Mutable)Iterable<R!>!>! ) : Observable<R!>! cannot be applied to 
DCSltem? )